# Robots.txt on Heroku Rails app unreachable by Google crawl

Tags: heroku, web-crawler, seo, robots.txt

Google can not access our robots.txt file when trying to crawl our site.... www.spokenvote.org

In Google's Webmaster tools, Fetch as Google, the error reads: Unreachable robots.txt

We have the exact same code deployed on on another Heroku app, staging.spokenvote.org, where Google is able to access the robots.txt fine.

Tailing the Heroku logs, the error message thrown by Heroku is an H13:

2014-01-04T21:11:32.042768+00:00 app[web.1]: !! Rack application returned nil body. Probably you wanted it to be an empty string?
2014-01-04T21:11:32.042879+00:00 app[web.1]: !! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
2014-01-04T21:11:32.053281+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path=/robots.txt host=www.spokenvote.org fwd="66.249.66.196" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=9ms status=503 bytes=0

Any ideas what is happening?

Spokenvote Team

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is server configuration. Try superuser or the webmaster SE sites.

Comment: On accessing to www.spokenvote.org/robots.txt I have the following error: Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Comment: Marc, with all due respect this question is an SEO question on the Heroku environment. Most programming issues have an element of configuration to them.

Comment: Too bad the question is on hold, as I would like to publish the answer. I guess I'll do it here: The inaccessible robots.txt file had to do with an unhappy memcachier / Dalli server.  Good to know your cache server can cause this files to fail to serve on Heroku, even if you can see those files in your browser. If you are seeing Heroku Dalli errors, your site may appear to run, but for the above reason you should fix any such Dalli errors.